# stationary states with a single eigenvalue with positive real part and eigenvector (1,-1,0,...,0)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, jacobian

Suppose we have a system of nonlinear ODEs over the variables x,y,.... which range over the positive reals.  Suppose we have a stationary state S whose jacobian matrix has a single eigenvalue with positive real part. And finally suppose that we know that the algebraic multiplicity of the later eigenvalue is equal to 1, and that the associated eigenvector is equal to (1,-1,0,...,0). Can one claim that perturbations of S generate dynamics along which the quantity represented by either x or y vanishes, while the quantity represented by the other variable grows?

Comment: Is equilibrium hyperbolic? In that case your statement is definitely locally true

Comment: It is hyperbolic. All the eigenvalues but one have a negative real part. How local is the conclusion? Is it possible to say something global?

Comment: By Adamar-Perron theorem there is an unstable manifold which is tangent to $(1, -1, 0, ... , 0)$. At least locally when you move on the unstable manifold $x$ grows, $y$ decreases. Moving near gives almost the same conclusion, though it might be trickier to get (but it feels that it's still not very hard). I think that this is hardly true when you're far from equilibrium.

Comment: Hadamard, of course. I always forget the right way to write his surname.